# How to merge data from different column when data is not null?

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have a table with different columns like so

```
CREATE TABLE survey(
id int(11) not null auto_increment,
what_is_your_name VARCHAR(255),
how_old_are_you varchar(20),
your_occupation varchar(255)
...
...
...
)
```

I need to build an output from the results of the survey table but I only need to concat the values if the column is not null.

So I want the final string to look like this if all the values are provided
NAME IS: [what_is_your_name]
AGE: [how_old_are_you]
OCCUPATION: [your_occupation]

if only 2 values are provided but the [what_is_your_name] is null then the output should be like this
NAME IS: [what_is_your_name]
OCCUPATION: [your_occupation]

However, I only want to concat the value is the values are not null.
Please note that the table above has a lot more question but I have only posted some of the table to explain the problem.

How can I do that in MySQL?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need that in mysql? If so - explire `CONCAT()` and `IFNULL()`/`COALESCE()`/`IF()` functions

Comment: Yes I need that is mysql because I have to generate the string and then insert it into a different table. I am not using a scripting language so it has to be done with SQL.  Can you please give me an example of how can I do that?

Comment: In my comment after a question you successfully answered there is a list of functions you need to be aware of to accomplish your task. Did you intentionally miss them expecting we do all the job for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', 
         COALESCE(CONCAT('NAME: ', what_is_your_name), ''),
         COALESCE(CONCAT('AGE: ', how_old_are_you), ''),
         COALESCE(CONCAT('OCCUPATION: ', your_occupation), '')) survey_details
  FROM survey
```

Sample output:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| survey_details                                    |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| NAME: john AGE: 35 OCCUPATION: Software Developer |
| NAME: mark  OCCUPATION: Unemployed                |
| NAME: helen AGE: 35                               |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c349/1)** demo